# Symfony2.5, Length Validation maxMessage attribute shows message with placeholder string instead of "max" value

Tags: php, validation, symfony, constraints

I am using Symfony2.5, below is my field in an entity with `Length` validation constraint.

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *          groups={"registration"},
     *          message = "Field is required"
     * )
     *
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      max = 50,
     *      groups={"registration"},
     *      maxMessage = "Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters length"
     * )
     *
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $firstName;
```

Validation works when I enter more than 50 character but it shows message like below

```
Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters length
```

I want value max which is **50** instead  instead of  **{{ limit }}**.

Any idea which tiny part is missing ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there are 2 asterisks in your annotation that shouldn't be there, it's a typo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703395/symfony2-validator-message-which-variables-are-available

Comment: Please be sure there is no whitespace in your message

Comment: * were added by mistake - gp_sflover and How can an error message be without white space - Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

`{{ limit }} The lower/max limit` – not working

Use:

```
{{ max }}   The upper limit
{{ min }}   The lower limit
{{ value }} The current (invalid) value
```